# Text and figure animation

Tags: beamer

This might be a trivial question but I am a novice LaTeX user.
I want the text to appear first followed by three figures one at a time. I use \pause after the text for this purpose. However, somehow the first figure never shows up, it starts with the second one.

I provided my code below. Will you please tell me what I am doing wrong?
You need three figures to run the code smoothly. I wanted to add them here but could not figure out how to do it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Montpellier}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}[triangle]
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate body}{size=\large}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[triangle]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Paper in a Nutshell }
\begin{itemize} 
    \item Focus on the Netherlands 
    \item 252 manufacturing industries over the period 1995-2010 \pause
\end{itemize} 

\vspace{0.5cm} 

\begin{center}
    \includegraphics<1>[width=0.9\linewidth]{nutshellwagesCROPPED}
    \includegraphics<2>[width=0.9\linewidth]{nutshellwagescompetitionCROPPED}
    \includegraphics<3>[width=0.9\linewidth]{nutshellCROPPED}
\end{center}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could try without the `\pause` and instead use `\includegraphicxs<2>` for the first image, `<3>` for the second and `<4>` for the third image.

Comment: @leandriis Indeed! I was using 1, 2, 3 so it needs to be 2, 3, 4. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Montpellier}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}[triangle]
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate body}{size=\large}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[triangle]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Paper in a Nutshell }
\begin{itemize}
    \item Focus on the Netherlands 
    \item 252 manufacturing industries over the period 1995-2010 
\end{itemize} 
\pause
\vspace{0.5cm} 
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics<+>[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
    \includegraphics<+>[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image-b}%
    \includegraphics<+>[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image-c}%
\end{center}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion also works nicely.

Comment: @uselessuser OK, I misread the question and modified my answer accordingly. The reason why in your code the first figure is not shown is that you are using `<1>` after `\pause`. It is arguably simpler to use `<+>` instead of explicit numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your informative reply. I am a new LaTex user so even tiny issues take time to figure out.